# Oracle SQL insert into statement ORA-00979

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a query below:

```
SELECT count(*) AS my_table_count
    ,my_table_date_value
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table_value = 500
GROUP BY my_table_date_value
```

This returns an array/two column table of the count and the date where the value is `500`. Which is what I want.

However, i created a table like this for the results of the above query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table (
 my_table_count NUMBER(10)
,my_table_date_value DATE
,my_table_value NUMBER(38)
)
```

What I want to do is fill the new table with all of the data from the first query, where `my_table_value > 0`

I tried using insert into (select...), but I'm not sure how to populate the `my_table_value` that way. I'm thinking iterating from 1 to the `max(my_table_value)` would do it but i'm not sure how to write this in Oracle SQL.

The result I want is where I can query `my_new_table` instead of using the first query as following:

```
SELECT my_table_count
      ,my_table_date_value
FROM my_new_table
WHERE my_table_value = 500;
```

---

EDIT

Here's what I do now for one value (say 500). All I want to do is go back and get the values 0-499 in the table.

```
 SET my_value = 500;
 SET sqlString = 'select COUNT(*) AS MY_COUNT,MY_DATE from MY_TABLE where MY_VALUE=? group by MY_DATE';
        SET rows[] = <query result, with my_value = 500>
        DECLARE index INTEGER 1;
        FOR result as r.rows[] DO
            SET count = result.MY_COUNT;
            SET my_date = result.MY_DATE;
            insert into MY_NEW_TABLE(MY_COUNT,MY_DATE,MY_VALUE)
            VALUES(count,my_date,my_value);
            SET index = index + 1;
        END FOR;
```

All I want to do is modify this, so it inserts everything from 1 to max(my_value)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Your suggested table has three columns, but the query returns only two.  Sample data would be a big help to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I know, what I want in the new table the third column mapped to the WHERE of the first query. So the new table has the 2 values the first query returns, as well as a 3rd value which will be what's in the WHERE currently

Comment: If you are going from two to three columns you will need to provide a value for the new column. To make it easy fill it with a default value and go back and update the value after copying the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain this is what you're after, but it sounds like you want to grab all the rough data into your "my_new_table" and then sift through it later ..

```
  insert into my_new_table
     ( my_table_count,
       my_table_date_value,
       my_table_value )
  select count(*) as my_table_count,
           my_table_date_value ,
           my_table_value
    from my_table 
   where my_table_value > 0
   group by my_table_date_value,
            my_table_value
```

(Note: untested, since no sample data, no create scripts, etc .. ie nothing to go on :( )

Comment: Ok, I've read it ... seems like what I put is still the solution for you ? have you tried it ? If it doesn't work please be sure to show what it does/doesn't do, what you want, and why you want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create table as select` for this. This way you can add your new columns to the new table. Also, you can alter the table should something change.

```
create table my_new_table as
select count(*) as my_table_count,my_table_date_value,my_table_value
from my_table 
where my_table_value = 500 --add more conditions when needed
group by my_table_date_value
```